# Typescript/React-Native: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types, asyncstorage

I am learning `typescript` with `React-Native` and I want to use `AsyncStorage` library. When setting my state after reading value from the storage, I got this problem:

> const value: string | null Argument of type 'string | null' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type
> 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

The App is showing the value but I want to learn how to solve the problem. I guess I have to assign a `type` to the `useState`, but do not know how to assign `SetStateAction` type.

How do I set the type to the `useState` to solve this problem?

This is the sample code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  
  async function saveValue(key: string, value: string) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
  
  async function readValue(key: string) {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    setValue(value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    saveValue('123', 'Hello world! ');
    readValue('123');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you.

Comment: try `useState<string[]>([])`

Comment: @MicFung it did not change the problem

Comment: Are you sure the initial value of state `value` is an empty array?

Comment: The problem is AsyncStorage.getItem(key) is returning string or null and it is not compatible with either never[] or string[]. As @Viet mentioned, may be you consider to change your type or tell us the use case of using array

Comment: If your state is storing the value (string or null) from the async storage `const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>('');` should be what you need

Comment: @MicFung Thank you. ``const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>('');`` solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `const [value,setValue] = useState<string | null>('');` fixed the issue as suggested by @Mic Fung. This is the resulting code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>('');
    
async function saveValue(key: string, value: string) {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }

async function readValue(key: string) {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    setValue(value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    saveValue('123', 'Hello world! ');
    readValue('123');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{value}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

## Hello world!